# Nested postcss at-rules are not removed

Tags: postcss

## [Interactive Fiddle](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/76a444ec55ba5d9073fd8589bd65fc50/f8e0cddcbffce42ed091c8eb491fa79c6e99b27c)

Here is a short reproducible example for the behavior I want to achieve:

```
var postcss = require('postcss');
var plugin = postcss.plugin('keepme', () => (root) => {
  root.walkAtRules(/keepme|removeme/, (atRule) => {
    if (atRule.name === 'keepme') {
      atRule.replaceWith(atRule.nodes);
    } else {
      atRule.remove();
    }
  });
});
postcss([plugin]).process(`
  @keepme {
    @removeme {
      .selector { color: red; }
    }
  }
`).then(result => console.log(result.css));
```

Given the input

```
  @keepme {
    @removeme {
      .selector { color: red; }
    }
  }
```

I would like this to return an empty string.

Instead, I receive the output

```
@removeme {
  .selector { color: red; }
}
```

The `@keepme` rule seems to correctly replace itself with its nodes (which is then not executed?).

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replaceWith`](http://api.postcss.org/node.es6.html#line229) is implemented like this:

```
/**
 * Inserts node(s) before the current node and removes the current node.
 *
 * @param {...Node} nodes - node(s) to replace current one
 *
 * @example
 * if ( atrule.name == 'mixin' ) {
 *   atrule.replaceWith(mixinRules[atrule.params]);
 * }
 *
 * @return {Node} current node to methods chain
 */
replaceWith(...nodes) {
    if (this.parent) {
        for (let node of nodes) {
            this.parent.insertBefore(this, node);
        }
        this.remove();
    }
    return this;
}
```

Given the list of at-rules to traverse:

1. @keepme
2. @removeme

The rule-walker keeps an index of the currently-inspected rule. At index 1 it finds `keepme`.
`keepme.replaceWith(removeme)` will insert `removeme` ***before*** `keepme`, then continue walking the ast...

Since `removeme` was moved ahead, the walker has moved past it, and will not execute that rule.

The fix is to modify `replaceWith` so it will move the child nodes ***after*** the inspected rule.

```
  root.walkAtRules(/keepme|removeme/, (atRule) => {
    if (atRule.name === 'keepme') {
      if (atRule.parent) {
        for (let node of atRule.nodes.reverse()) {
          atRule.parent.insertAfter(atRule, node);
        }
      }
    }
    atRule.remove();
  });
```

This works as intended: [Interactive fiddle](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0ff8f49318ebbf88b0c347e7c7a1e221/122e5d1d587255a4459c6eb18561fafecc4aeea7)